# Image with signature not positioned as expected

Tags: swift, swiftui, draw

I am working on a SwiftUI project where I want to overlay a signature image on top of another image and allow users to manipulate the position, scale, and rotation of the signature image. However, I'm encountering issues with the positioning of the signature image, and it's not appearing where I expect it to be.

I've tried to set up gestures for dragging, scaling, and rotating the signature image, but it's not behaving as expected. The signature image seems to be offset (it's saving it in the left top corner) and scaled incorrectly (no matter the scaling, it will be always very tiny).

Could someone please help me identify what might be causing the problem with the positioning and scaling of the signature image?

Here's the relevant code:

```
struct SignatureAddingView: View {
    
    @State var scannedImage: UIImage = UIImage()
    
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var scaleAnchor: UnitPoint = .center
    @State private var lastScale: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var debug = ""
        
    @State private var location: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    @GestureState private var fingerLocation: CGPoint? = nil
    @GestureState private var startLocation: CGPoint? = nil
    
    @State private var scaling: CGFloat = 1.0 // Add a state variable for scaling
    @State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0.0 // Add a state variable for rotation
        
    var simpleDrag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                var newLocation = startLocation ?? location // 3
                newLocation.x += value.translation.width
                newLocation.y += value.translation.height
                self.location = newLocation
            }.updating($startLocation) { (value, startLocation, transaction) in
                startLocation = startLocation ?? location // 2
            }
    }
    
    var fingerDrag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating($fingerLocation) { (value, fingerLocation, transaction) in
                fingerLocation = value.location
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                let magnificationGesture = MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged{ gesture in
                        scaleAnchor = .center
                        scale = lastScale * gesture
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
                    }
                
                let dragGesture = DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        var newOffset = lastOffset
                        newOffset.width += gesture.translation.width
                        newOffset.height += gesture.translation.height
                        offset = newOffset
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
                    }
                
                ZStack {
                    
                    Image(uiImage: scannedImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2,
                                  y: geometry.size.height / 2)
                        .scaleEffect(scale, anchor: scaleAnchor)
                        .offset(offset)
                        .gesture(dragGesture)
                        .gesture(magnificationGesture)
                    
                    ZStack {
                        
                        if let image = loadImageFromDocumentDirectory(filename: "signature.png") {
                            
                            ZStack {
                                
                                Rectangle()
                                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1, dash: [5]))
                                    .fill(.blue)
                                
                                Image(uiImage: image)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                
                            }
                                VStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    HStack {
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                        
                                        Circle()
                                            .fill(Color.green) // Change the circle color as needed
                                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20) // Adjust the size of the circle as needed
                                    }
                                    .padding(.trailing, -18)
                                    .padding(.bottom, -13)
                                }
                            )
                            .position(location)
                            .gesture(
                                simpleDrag.simultaneously(with: fingerDrag)
                            )
                            
                        }
                            
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(rotationAngle)), anchor: .center)
                    .scaleEffect(scaling)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            }

        }
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.3))
        .overlay(
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    saveImageWithSignatures()
                } label: {
                    Text("Save")
                }
            }
        )
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
    
    // Function to combine the original image with the signature overlay
    func combineImages() -> UIImage? {
        // Create a UIGraphicsImageRenderer to draw the combined image
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: scannedImage.size)

        let combinedImage = renderer.image { ctx in
            // Draw the original image
            scannedImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: scannedImage.size))

            // Calculate the position and size of the signature overlay
            let signatureRect = CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 100, height: 100)

            // Draw the signature overlay
            if let signatureImage = loadImageFromDocumentDirectory(filename: "signature.png") {
                signatureImage.draw(in: signatureRect)
            }
        }

        return combinedImage
    }

    // Function to save the modified image with the signature overlay
    func saveImageWithSignatures() {
        // Combine the images
        if let combinedImage = combineImages() {
            // Save the combined image to the document directory
            saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: combinedImage, filename: "modified_img.jpeg")
        }
    }
    
    // Function to save an image to the document directory
    func saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: UIImage, filename: String) {
        if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
            let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)
            do {
                try data.write(to: fileURL)
                print("Image saved to document directory: \(fileURL)")
            } catch {
                print("Error saving image: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loadImageFromDocumentDirectory(filename: String) -> UIImage? {
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        
        do {
            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            return UIImage(data: imageData)
        } catch {
            print("Error loading image: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
    
// NOTE: - My image displaying logic
    private func fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: GeometryProxy) {
        let newScale: CGFloat = .minimum(.maximum(scale, 1), 4)
        let screenSize = geometry.size
        
        let originalScale = scannedImage.size.width / scannedImage.size.height >= screenSize.width / screenSize.height ?
            geometry.size.width / scannedImage.size.width :
            geometry.size.height / scannedImage.size.height
        
        let imageWidth = (scannedImage.size.width * originalScale) * newScale
        
        var width: CGFloat = .zero
        if imageWidth > screenSize.width {
            let widthLimit: CGFloat = imageWidth > screenSize.width ?
                (imageWidth - screenSize.width) / 2
                : 0

            width = offset.width > 0 ?
                .minimum(widthLimit, offset.width) :
                .maximum(-widthLimit, offset.width)
        }
        
        let imageHeight = (scannedImage.size.height * originalScale) * newScale
        var height: CGFloat = .zero
        if imageHeight > screenSize.height {
            let heightLimit: CGFloat = imageHeight > screenSize.height ?
                (imageHeight - screenSize.height) / 2
                : 0

            height = offset.height > 0 ?
                .minimum(heightLimit, offset.height) :
                .maximum(-heightLimit, offset.height)
        }
        
        let newOffset = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        lastScale = newScale
        lastOffset = newOffset
        withAnimation() {
            offset = newOffset
            scale = newScale
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you apply the different transformations is important. I would suggest, you make it **scaling** followed by **rotation** followed by **offset**. This way, if any part of the stack should be excluded from scaling (such as overlays for buttons) then these can be added to the view after the scaling modifier has been applied. It is particularly important that the offset is applied after the rotation. If the offset comes before rotation then it shifts the center of rotation and the image will no longer by rotated around its mid point.

I would have expected, the transformations should only be made to the signature overlay, not to the underlying image. In the code above, I think you are applying some transformations to the underlying image too.

Scaling and rotation can be applied cumulatively, using the end state of the previous adjustment as the start state of the next. However, scaling should probably not be applied cumulatively.

My understanding is that the user should be able to apply scaling by moving the bottom corner. The drag location can then be treated as the new corner location, keeping the mid point unchanged. Therefore:

> scalingFactor = <distance from center to drag location> / <default distance from center to corner>

If an offset and rotation are also involved, these need to be taken into consideration when determining the mid point and corner position.

The scaling factor that this formula gives you should be applied as an absolute value and not compounded by applying to an existing scaling factor. You probably also want to enforce minimum and maximum scaling factors, so that the image is not shrunk to a ridiculously small size or bloated too large.

To see all of this working, please try the example I gave in my [answer to your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77065727/20386264). Here is the function from that answer that performs the scaling:

```swift
private func performScale(dragLocation: CGPoint) {
    let midPoint = midPoint
    let dX = dragLocation.x - midPoint.x
    let dY = dragLocation.y - midPoint.y
    let draggedDiagonalLength = 2 * ((dX * dX) + (dY * dY)).squareRoot()
    let unscaledDiagonalLength = (
            (defaultSignatureWidth * defaultSignatureWidth) +
            (defaultSignatureHeight * defaultSignatureHeight)
        ).squareRoot()
    let draggedScaleFactor = draggedDiagonalLength / unscaledDiagonalLength
    scaleFactor = min(1.5, max(0.5, draggedScaleFactor))
}
```