# How can I drag and zoom properly with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, zooming, gesture

I'm trying to implement a drag and magnification gesture on an image.
Seems very difficult to do with SwiftUI !
I managed to make it work, but I still have 3 problems that I can't solve :

1. simultaneousGesture does not work : impossible to drag and zoom at the same time
2. the gestures have a lag at start when you begin to drag or zoom the image
3. The magnification gesture does not zoom where your fingers are so it's weird for user

The best would be to have the same behavior as on Google maps, Photos, Waze, ...

Does anyone know how I could improve ?

Here is my code (just change the image) :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var scale: CGFloat = 2.0
@State private var location: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 400)
@GestureState private var startLocation: CGPoint? = nil
@State private var currentZoom: CGFloat = 1.0

let zoomMin = 1.0
let zoomMax = 8.0

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
        Image("myImage")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .scaleEffect((min(max(self.scale * currentZoom, zoomMin), zoomMax)))
            .position(location)
            .gesture(simpleDrag)
            .simultaneousGesture(magnification)         // problem 1 : SimultaneousGesture does not work : impossible to drag and zoom at the same time
    }
}

// Problem 2 : The simpleDrag gesture has a lag at start when you begin to drag the image

var simpleDrag: some Gesture {
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged { value in
            var newLocation = startLocation ?? location
            newLocation.x += value.translation.width
            newLocation.y += value.translation.height
            self.location = newLocation
        }
        .updating($startLocation) { (value, startLocation, transaction) in
            startLocation = startLocation ?? location
        }
}

// Problem 3 : The magnification gesture does not zoom where your fingers are, so it's weird for user

var magnification: some Gesture {
    MagnificationGesture()
        .onChanged {
            currentZoom = $0
        }
        .onEnded {_ in
            scale = min(max(self.scale * currentZoom, zoomMin), zoomMax)
            currentZoom = 1
        }
}
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The answer to this question might help: [How to implement three gestures at the same time in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77065727/20386264)